Prove the unbounded sequence $\left\{{a_n} \right\}$ has a subsequence $\left\{a_{p_n} \right\}$ such that $\frac{1}{a_{p_n}}\rightarrow 0$.

Let $\left\{{a_n} \right\}$ be an unbounded sequence. Prove that there
exists a subsequence $\left\{{a_{p_n}} \right\}$ of $\left\{{a_n}\right\}$ such that $\left\{ \frac{1}{a_{p_n}} \right\}$  converges to
$0$.

So this is a problem from an elementary real analysis textbook through which I'm currently working my way up, on my own.
Now, this seems like it should be an easy problem. However, as non-math major from an engineering background working out the details, setting up the sequence, proof write-up, and the like, is a bit of challenge for me. I cannot, for example, be sure whether I have done it correctly (is it generally OK-ish?), or perhaps I should have started off (how?) with some recursive definition.
So, what do you think?

Proof: If we prove there exists a subsequence $\left\{a_{p_n} \right\}$ of $\left\{a_{n} \right\}$ with nonzero terms such that it
converges to $ \infty$, we are done. Let $S = \left\{n : a_n =\text{sup} \left\{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\right\}, a_n \neq 0\right\} $.
The set $S$ is infinite; it can be expressed as a strictly increasing
sequence $\left\{p_n \right\}$ which is then used to form the
subsequence $\left\{a_{p_n} \right\}$. Now, we prove $\left\{a_{p_n}\right\}$ is an unbound increasing sequence.
To show that it is increasing, we note that, since $\left\{ a_1, a_2,\dots, a_{p_n}\right\} \subseteq \left\{ a_1, a_2, \dots,a_{p_{n+1}}\right\}$, it follows from the definition of $S$ that
$a_{p_n} \leq a_{p_{n+1}}$.
To show that it is unbounded, first we prove that $a_{p_n} \geq a_n$.
Let n be arbitrary. Since $p_n \in S$, we have $a_{p_n} =\text{sup}\left\{a_1,\dots,a_{p_n}\right\}$. But $n \leq p_n$, so $a_n\in \left\{a_1,\dots,a_{p_n}\right\}$. Thus, $a_{p_n} \geq a_n$. Now,
let $\left\{a_{p_n} \right\}$ be bounded. Let $M$ be an upper bound
for this. Because $\left\{a_{n} \right\}$ is unbounded, for some $N\in \mathbb{Z^+}$, we have $a_N > M$. Since $a_{p_N} \geq a_N$, it
follows that $a_{p_N} > M$. Therefore,  $\left\{a_{p_n} \right\}$,
too, is unbounded.


You haven't proven the sequence to be strictly increasing.

One problem is that the sequence might contain negative terms. For example, if $a_n=-n$, then $S={0}$ is not infinite. You'll probably have to use absolute values in most places.

True. I missed that case. So it seems if I prove this for $\left|a_n\right|$ it should be ok, even if long winded.

Your proof is good when the sequence does not have an upper bound. A similar proof would handle the case where it does not have a lower bound.

Choose $a_{n_1}>1$, then, for $k>1$ choose $n_k>n_{k-1}$ such that $a_{n_k}>\max(a_{n_{k-1}},k)$.

@Steen82 Thank you.

@Mittens I see it now. This can directly be shown to diverge to infinity.

It's easier than this. Since $|a_n|$ is unbounded, given any $k\in\mathbb N$, there must exist $n(k)\in\mathbb N$ such that $|a_{n(k)}| \geq k$. You can choose $n(k)$ increasing in $k$ (why?). Therefore, $1/|a_{n(k)}|\leq 1/k$ for every $k$. You get then $1/a_{n(k)}\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$.
